# If $n=N^2m$ for squarefree $m$, then $n$ is the sum of two squares if $m$ has no prime factor of the form $4k+3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, square-numbers

My question is ;

> Let $n$ be $n=N^{2} m$ , where m is a squarefree integer.
> Then $n$ can be written that as a sum of two integer squares, if $m$ contains no prime factor of the form $4k+3$.

I have a reference here. Look at this solution please.  And notice that m is a integer.

"Suppose that m has no prime factor of the form $4 k+3$
if $m=1,$ then $n=N^{2}+0^{2}$ and we are done. In the case $m>1,le t$ $\mu=p_{1} p_{2} \cdots p_{r}$ be the factorization of m into a product of distinct primes. Each of these primes $p_{i},$ being equal to 2 or of the form $4 k+1,$ can be written as a sum of two squares. Now, the identity

$
\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)\left(c^{2}+d^{2}\right)=(a c+b d)^{2}+(a d-b c)^{2}
$
shows that the product of two ( and any finite number by induction) integers, each of which is representable as a sum of two squares, is likewise so representable. Thus, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ satisfying $m=x^{2}+y^{2},$ and so
$
\left.n=N^{2} m=N^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)=(N x)^{2}+\ (N y\right)^{2}
$
which completes the proof."

Is the solution right for this question?

And What are your different ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Looks good as long as you assume Fermat's two-square theorem without proof.

Comment: Agreed. With a little more work, you can prove it's an if-and-only-if statement.

Comment: thanks. So what changes can i make to solution and how can i improve it? @Clement yung

Comment: i have its proof (if and only if statement) but the question asks only one statement. so what do you suggest me else? @Gerry Myerson

Comment: yes. i see clearly it now. How can i solve it without fermat theorem?Can you give some hints? :)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to prove it without using Fermat, or some equivalent statement about factorization in the Gaussian integers. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31113/zagiers-one-sentence-proof-of-a-theorem-of-fermat may interest you, it refers to https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2323918/fulltext.pdf also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: thank you very much. i will investigate it.

Comment: Do I also use these references?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74132/explicit-formula-for-fermats-4k1-theorem and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-do-you-prove-that-a-prime-is-the-sum-of-two-squares-iff-it-is-congruent-to-1@Gerry Myerson

Comment: If you find them helpful, sure. But you've mangled the second URL, and also if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.