# Gauss formulas to decompose a prime in the sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for a demonstration of the formulas to decompose a prime $p\equiv 1$ $mod$ $4$  in the sum of two squares, cited in H. Davenport, The Higher Arithmetic. I have not found anything on the web. Thank you.

If $p=4k+1$ , with $p$ prime,

$p=x^2 + y^2$ , with

$x\equiv\frac{(2k)!}{2(k!)^2}$ $mod$ $p$

$y\equiv(2k)! x$ $mod$ $p$

and

$x < \frac{p}{2},y < \frac{p}{2}$

Comment: Dear Vincenzo, You probably mean a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (not $-1$).  Regards,

Comment: P.S. You may also be interested in [this question and its answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5877/221).

Comment: Thank you for viewing Matt E, I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$x^2+y^2=x^2(1+((2k)!)^2)=x^2[1+(1)(2)\cdots(2k)(-1)(-2)\cdots(-2k)]\ ,$$
this being true because we have inserted an *even* number of negatives.  Modulo $p$, therefore,
$$\eqalign{x^2+y^2
  &\equiv x^2[1+(1)(2)\cdots(2k)(2k+1)\cdots(4k-1)(4k)]\cr
  &\equiv x^2[1+(p-1)!]\cr
  &\equiv0\cr}$$
because $(p-1)!\equiv-1$ modulo $p$ by Wilson's Theorem.  Therefore $x^2+y^2$ is a multiple of $p$.

**Edit** following comments from the OP and revision of the question: this does not guarantee that $x^2+y^2$ is **equal** to $p$, however it appears that the extra conditions $|x|<\frac{p}{2}$ and $|y|<\frac{p}{2}$ do ensure this.

Comment: I have observed that if $x < \frac{p}{2},y < \frac{p}{2}$ the formulas work; for example: $p=29$, for $x=5$ and $y=2$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, for all x, because it uses only the ratio $\frac{y}{x}$, but $x$ has a particular expression as a function of $n$, and this implies that $x$ and $y$ solve the problem; of course, the formulas do not have a practical use for large numbers because of the factorial!

Comment: @Vincenzo, could you please give details of the calculations in the case $p=13$?  Perhaps I misunderstood the formulae you gave.

Comment: David, you can directly see the reference that I quoted here, http://books.google.it/books?id=pGDckKsed3EC&pg=PA115&hl=it&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false , at the end of page 121. There is the example for $p=29$, and it is specified that must be " $x$ and $y$ numerically less than $\frac{1}{2}p$".

Comment: In the case $p=13$, $x\equiv10\equiv-3,$ and $y\equiv11\equiv-2,$ $mod$ $13$; $x$ and $y$ are less than $\frac{{13}}{2}$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 9+4 = 13$

Comment: @Vincenzo The usual meaning of reducing a number modulo $p$ is that the result should be from $0$ to $p-1$.  Perhaps you could clarify your original post by stating that $x,y$ are to be numerically less than $\frac{1}{2}p$.

Comment: David you are right, I correct the original post to avoid misunderstandings. With this clarification, do you have any idea to prove the formulas? I think they are interesting in theory though not useful in practical calculations.