# Primes, Fermat's Theorem on sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory

Is there any method that I can follow to calculate $x$ and $y$ such that $p= x^{2}+y^{2} $ where $p$ is a prime and $p \equiv  1 ({mod}\ 4)$. Fermats theorem of sum of two squares.

Comment: Use the Euclidean algorithm in $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ and Cornacchia, see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5895/242)