# Can 2018 be written as a sum of two squares? If can, what is the expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Can $2018$ be written as a sum of two squares?
>
> If it can be, what are the numbers?

I know the first answer is it can be because $2018=2\times1009$ and $1009\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. But I cannot find the numbers.

Comment: If all you care about is the numbers, then [wolframalpha can help](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2018%3Dx%5E2%2By%5E2).

Comment: By hit and trial, you can verify that $2018 = 13^2 + \cdots$

Comment: For a small number like this, just make a column in a spreadsheet with $1$ to $45$ then =sqrt(2018-left^2) will make it easy to find.  Just search by eye for the entries without decimals.  They leap out.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828694/algorithm-for-finding-the-representation-of-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-two-squares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $2018 = 2\times 1009$ (as prime factorization). Since $1009$ is an odd prime of the form $4k+1$, it can be written as a sum of two squares $1009 = a^2+b^2$. Together with $2 = 1^2 + 1^2$,
[Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2 = (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2$$
tell us $2018 = (a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2$.

The task reduces to rewrite $1009$ as a sum of two squares. In addition to
seaching by brute force, one can use algorithms described in
answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime/5895#5895) to determine $a,b$ efficiently.  At the end, one find $$1009 = 28^2+15^2 \quad\implies\quad 2018 = 43^2 + 13^2$$

A good reference of these sort of algorithms will be Henri Cohen's book
[A course in Computation Algebraic Number Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540556400). Take a look at that if you need more details.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct my friend,as per Brahmagupta's Fibonacci identity,it says that-$a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2$=$a^2c^2-2acbd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+2adbc+b^2c^2$=$a^2c^2+2acbd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2-2adbc+b^2c^2$ just as you are writing 1009=784+225 and 2018=1849+169

Comment: Now if you want to use only 43 and 13 to represent 1009 then you can write as follows:$$1009=[(\frac{1}{4}){(43+13)^2+(43-13)^2}]$$=                                 $$(\frac{1}{4}){(56^2+30^2)$$ = $$(\frac{1}{4})(3136+900)$$