# Integer Solutions of $ x^2+y^2=161701$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to get all integer solutions of $ x^2+y^2=161701$ using the below theorem I have got the following pair $(401,30) , (399,50)$ because $161701$ is of the form 
$ 4k+1$ , But I want any analytic method to solve that kind of equation ?

**Theorem**:A positive integer $n$ is properly representable as a sum of two relatively prime squares if and only if the prime factors of $n$ are all of the form $4k+1$, except for the prime $2$ which may occur to at most the first power.

Comment: The theorem is incorrectly stated. $n$ can have factors $p^2$ for any $p$ eg $18=3^2+3^2$

Comment: Since the prime factorization of your number is $$161701=101 \cdot 1601$$ there exist only two ways to write it as the sum of two squares. So, you found all of them.

Comment: @Crostul Two expressions as unordered sums of positive integer squares.  Here, since integers are stated in the question, signs can be changed (order is apparently irrelevant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, we factorize $161701$ in integers, it is:
$$
161701 = 101 \cdot 1601
\ .
$$
Now we use the following result about the ring of the Gaussian integers,
$$
R=\Bbb Z[i]\ .
$$
A prime $p>0$ in the integers, seen now as an element in the unique factorization ring  of gaussian integers, has the following chances:

- it is ramified, only in the case $p=2$, and here in the decomposition of $2$ as product of two conjugated (prime) elements $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ the two factors are associated. (They differ by a unit.)
- it splits as a product of two conjugated (prime) elements $p=(a+bi)(a-bi)$.
- it is inert, i.e. also a prime in the ring of gaussian integers.

The quadratic reciprocity laws tell us when we can split and when not. (Last two cases.) In our case, the primes are congruent to one modulo $4$, so we can split uniquely:
$$
\begin{aligned}
101 &= 10^2+1^2 =(10+i)(10-i)\ ,\\
1601 &= 40^2+1^2 =(40+i)(40-i)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have the prime factor decomposition in $R$:
$$
161701 = (10+i)(10-i)(40+i)(40-i)\ .
$$
Each solution of $(x+iy)(x-iy)=161701$ corresponds (up to units) to grouping above the factors in two parts, in each part we have exactly one of $10\pm i$ and exactly one of $40\pm i$. This leads to the solutions obtained by expanding

- $x+iy=(10+i)(40+i)=399+50i$, and
- $x+iy=(10+i)(40-i)=401+30i$.

All integer solutions are obtained by also taking the conjugates, and also using the four units $1,i,-1,-i$. So we expect $16=4\cdot 4$ solutions with $x,y\in\Bbb Z$. (The computer confirms below.)

---

Some computer experiments:

```
sage: R.<j> = QuadraticField(-1)
sage: factor(161701)
101 * 1601
sage: factor(R(161701))
(j - 40) * (j - 10) * (j + 10) * (j + 40)
sage: (10+j)*(40+j)
50*j + 399
sage: (10+j)*(40-j)
30*j + 401
```

And all integer solutions:

```
sage: for x, y in cartesian_product( [ [-N..N], [-N..N] ] ):
....:     if x^2 + y^2 == 161701:
....:         print "x = %4s and y = %4s" % (x, y)
....:         
x = -401 and y =  -30
x = -401 and y =   30
x = -399 and y =  -50
x = -399 and y =   50
x =  -50 and y = -399
x =  -50 and y =  399
x =  -30 and y = -401
x =  -30 and y =  401
x =   30 and y = -401
x =   30 and y =  401
x =   50 and y = -399
x =   50 and y =  399
x =  399 and y =  -50
x =  399 and y =   50
x =  401 and y =  -30
x =  401 and y =   30
sage:
```

Comment: This was exactly what I had in mind, but it was too long to write.

Comment: I know, but somebody has to write it down, there are too many written or oral expositions where the details are missing. People at the beginning may get stuck before the structure gets the upper hand. I am trying to give full details, so that in the case of more, say seven factors over $\Bbb Z$, the "algorithm" of grouping and finding all solutions should be clear. Such "simple" numerical examples supporting a number theoretical structure are very important in the study and in fixing the theoretical input.

Comment: If you are interested in a method that solves $N=x^2 + y^2$ without having to factorize $N$, you can check this method out. It uses the properties of triangular numbers to solve for $x,y$.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972771/is-this-the-general-solution-of-finding-the-two-original-squares-that-add-up-to