# Solve $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{41} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Using Legendre's symbol, knowing that $41 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ we can solve said equation. Then, I looked at the residue classes and I just counted my way to the solution $x = 9$. Verifying, $9^2 = 81$ and $81 \equiv -1 \pmod{41} $. I was wondering if there was an actual way to solve the equation $$x^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{41}$$ using quadratic residue formulas or any other formula for that matter, instead of counting to get the solution.

Comment: I think you mean $41\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ in your first line.  Beyond that, I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: One possible approach which does rely on some random guessing, but not nearly as much: start with some random $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{41}$, such as $a = 2$.  Then, since we know $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{41}$, we can examine $a^5, a^{10}, a^{20}, a^{40}$ and if $a^5 \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{41}$, then one of those numbers will be equivalent to -1 (that's what has to happen just before reaching 1), and the number before that will be the desired square root.

Comment: Please include the question you are asking in the body of the post, not just in the subject line.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Well....you might get unlucky and start with say, $a=16$ which has order $5\pmod {41}$.

Comment: I have edited my post, I think it is clearer now

Comment: There's the Tonelli Shanks algorithm:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm  It emulates Newton's method for finding roots of functions.

Comment: @lulu Well, that's where the random guessing comes in - if you get unlucky then you make another random guess.  Then, since $a^5 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{41}$ has only 10 solutions, the probability of a random guess leading to a solution is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: So let's make it more interesting and solve $x^2+1\equiv 0 \bmod 4441$. :-)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5877/207316

Comment: With very small primes it is quick to write as the sum of two squares, $41= 25+16v = 5^2+4^2$ in my head. Therefore $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {41},$  and we have easy modular reciprocals for 4,5 as needed to proceed. I guess I put 5 in the denominator, $5 \cdot (-8) \equiv 5 \cdot 33 \equiv 1 \pmod{41}.$  So the fraction becomes $4 \cdot 33 = 132 \equiv 9 \pmod {41}$

Comment: $4441=60^2+29^2$  and $29 \cdot 1072 \equiv 1 \pmod {4441}$ Then $60 \cdot 1072 \equiv 2146 \pmod {4441}.$ Note that 2146 is the number of my post office box. And $2146^2 \equiv 4440 \pmod {4441}$

Comment: Here's a live version of Robin Chapman's [script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUstuwyAQvPsrpqmivBy5tnyKStWP6LkVTXDjxAGEsaL-fRcwIY7KATHs7uzswEE0uKhDv-Q55GqXgRbHnEH6oxF2MJJutpBoG1RYE3gjILpegGfZgQi0ukYOk2jUYMFQ-vP12HYChipfQtAt4jOYo0o3viW2sSquwORbuCNJcF2yVFEUDNUN85jMJ6njLMQQVBulbL3Uo9pn1Pbo76AalI5g6BR0NirVeCVZSerINrNKob_wrpulzDlqPP2bLYl-r-SPGYS0sAplKDuTZF0UtQcnxGmCbR-UvZtMFw0_5Tjn0MmK74fR70KkjKIM2_LB7_GJp4lT-Y8jaNNexOwWPmHjnix7b6UVhu-t9_drqVld3v4UGw2nHDI96CIeQnwVrbO_WhB0MimQ-vdUzdccm7uPEWoXPvRZbUqwRY4-h9sLHVChV38OA681&lang=python), trimmed to just compute sqrt(-1) mod p.

Comment: @PM2Ring And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6159/242) is Macsyma code, along with a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5895/242).

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is a prime, and $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then we can express $p$ as the sum of two squares: $p=x^2+y^2$. Then you have $x^2\equiv -y^2\pmod{p}$, and since $\gcd(y,p)=1$, you can find $z$ such that $zy\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Then $(xz)^2 = x^2z^2 \equiv -y^2z^2 = -1\pmod{p}$.

Here, $41=5^2+4^2$. Now, $4(10)=40\equiv -1\pmod{41}$, so $4(-10)\equiv 1\pmod{41}$. Thus, one solution is $5(-10)= -50\equiv 9\pmod{41}$.

---

Of course, part of this is cheating, since one way to establish that a prime $p$ can be written as a sum of two squares when $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ is to rely on the fact that the equation $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution.

Comment: So this method relies on finding the sum of 2 squares?

Comment: @Rodrigoss: Yes. Or you could find a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: I cannot really understand where did the $(xz)^2$ came from, would you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: If $x^2\equiv -y^2$, then multiplying both sides by $z^2$ gives $x^2z^2\equiv -y^2z^2$. The left hand side is $(xz)^2$, the right hand side is $-(yz)^2$, and $yz\equiv 1$, so you get $(xz)^2\equiv -1$.

Comment: Right, I see it now, I missed the connection