# Fermat's Christmas theorem on sums of two squares with Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Gaussian integers are the set:
$$\mathbb{Z}[\imath] =\{a+b\imath : a,b \in\mathbb{Z} \}$$
With norm:
$$\mathrm{N}(a+b\imath)=a^{2}+b^{2}.$$
It satisfies $\mathrm{N}(\alpha\cdot \beta )=\mathrm{N}(\alpha)\cdot\mathrm{N}( \beta )$

The units of $\mathbb{Z}[\imath]$ are  precisely: $1,-1,\imath,-\imath$

Result: If $p=4k+1$ ( p : prime), there are $x<p$  such that $p\mid(x^{2}+1)$

> $Theorem$: If $p$ is a prime with
> $p=4k+1$, then $p$ is an sum of two
> squares.
> *Proof.*
> If $p=4k+1$ there are $x<p$ such that $p\mid (x^{2}+1)$, then  $p\mid(x+\imath)(x-\imath)$.

Note that, if $p\mid (x+\imath)$, there are $(a+b\imath)$ such that:
$$(x+\imath)=p(a+b\imath)=pa+pb\imath.$$
This implies that $x=pa$, this is imposible as $x\lt p$.

Therefore $p\nmid(x+\imath)$, also $p\nmid(x-\imath)$.

Then $p$ is not an Gaussian prime, so $p = \alpha \beta$ with $\mathrm{N}(\alpha)\gt 1$ and $\mathrm{N}(\beta)\gt 1$.

If $ \alpha=a+b\imath $ and $\beta=c+d\imath$, we get:
$$\mathrm{N}(p)=\mathrm{N}(\alpha \beta)=\mathrm{N}\alpha\cdot\mathrm{N}\beta,$$
which implies:
$$p^{2}=(a^{2}+b^{2})(c^{2}+d^{2}).$$

Note that the last equation is an integer, so $(a^{2}+b^{2})|p^{2}$.

By this last equation $(a^{2}+b^{2}),(c^{2}+d^{2})\neq 1,$ so therefore:
$$p=a^{2}+b^{2}$$

**

> It's beautiful!  Does anyone have other
> proofs  ?

**

Comment: @Bryan: did you see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-do-you-prove-that-a-prime-is-the-sum-of-two-squares-iff-it-is-congruent-to-1

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate.  It is a fine question, but seems to be asking for the exact same thing as the question Chandru1 linked to.

Comment: In retrospect, the other question just asked for an explanation, not specifically for other proofs, so hopefully my vote wasn't hasty.  Nonetheless, I think having both open would be redundant; perhaps they could be merged?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, this is a good question. Perhaps bryan was not aware of the fact that this has been already asked.

Comment: I just want to know different proofs of this theorem, and I think the other question is different from mine ...

Comment: @Bryan Yocks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: I have a question about the uniqueness of $a$ and $b$. This proof shows that $$p=a^{2}+b^{2}$$ but, unless I'm mistaken, also that $$p=c^{2}+d^{2}$$ How can we show that these are in fact the same squares?

Comment: Nitpicking: how did you type the $i$ without the dot XD might look confusing to some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best viewed from a slightly more general perspective as follows. In any $\rm UFD$, if $\rm\ a\ $ is not prime, i.e.  $\rm\ a\:|\:bc\ $ but $\rm\ a\nmid b,\ a\nmid c\ $ then $\rm\ \gcd(a,b)\ $ is a *proper* factor of $\rm\:a\:$. Moreover this gcd can be computed  when a $\rm UFD$ has a constructive Euclidean algorithm, as does $\rm \mathbb Z[i]\:$. Therefore this yields a *constructive* proof that nonprime nonunits are reducible in Euclidean domains (i.e. the nontrivial half of the [equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/alternate-definition-of-prime-number/4399#4399) of irreducible and prime elements in $\rm UFDs$).

Applying this above [we deduce](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime/5895#5895) that $\rm\ gcd(p,x-i)\ = a + bi $ is a proper factor of $\rm\:p\:$, so it must have norm a proper factor of $\rm\ N(p) = p^2\ $, i.e. it must have norm $\rm\:p\:$. Therefore $\rm\ p = a^2 + b^2\ $ as desired. This leads to an elegant efficient few-line Euclidean algorithm to compute a representation of a prime $\rm\ p = 4k+1\ $ as a sum of two squares - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime/6159#6159) for an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proof by [Roger Heath-Brown](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/677/) and another by [John Ewell](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2323282).

Heath-Brown's proof was later adapted into a "one-sentence" proof by Zagier. Zagier's proof is available at the wikipedia link given in Sivaram's answer.

Comment: I met this proof in number theory class, is very beutiful ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice proof using [Minkowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowskis_theorem) which also proves the four-square theorem.  It is Proof #2 [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=14052&b=10589&).