# Sum of two relatively prime squares in two distinct ways

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I hope that this isn't simple because I've been scratching my head with it:

In David Burton's "Elementary Number Theory", there is a question that says that in 1647, Mersenne noted that when a number can be written as a sum of two relatively prime squares in two distinct ways, it is composite and can be factored as:

$n=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ implies $n=\frac{(ac+bd)(ac-bd)}{a+d)(a-d)}$.

The problem in the book merely asks the reader to use this for a particular example (n=493) but doesn't give a reason for the general case.

Now, my question is this: how was n factored in this way?

I've tried manipulating n in a few ways such as playing $n+n, n-n, n^2$ but I haven't had any luck. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: there are two nice articles by Brillhart on this and extensions. Euler's first note on the problem gave your formula and proved there was a nontrivial factorization of $n$ that can be found from it. Later, Euler gave a more cookbook answer, messier to prove.

Comment: $(ac+bd)(ac-bd) = a^2 c^2 - b^2 d^2 = a^2 (c^2 + d^2) - (a^2 + b^2) d^2 = n (a^2 - d^2) = n (a+d)(a-d)  $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I made jpegs of bits from the first Brillhart article,

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer has been very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ You can do this by taking gcds of Gaussian integers $\,\Bbb Z[i].\,$ Let $\,\alpha = a+bi,\ \beta = c+di.\ $ Then $\,\alpha\bar\alpha = n =  \beta\bar\beta.\,$ Since the rep's are different $\,\alpha\,$ is not associate to  $\,\beta\,$ or $\,\bar \beta.\,$ Nor can $\,\alpha\,$ be coprime to both (else it would be coprime to their product, since $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ is a UFD). So it is not coprime to one of them, say $\,\gamma = \gcd(\alpha,\beta)\,$ is a nonuit. Then $\,\gamma\bar\gamma\,$ is a proper factor of $\,n = \alpha\bar\alpha$.

**Remark** $\ $ This yields a constructive algorithm, using the simple [Euclidean algorithm in $\,\Bbb Z[i].\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6159/242)

This is best viewed from a slightly more general perspective as follows. In any $\rm UFD$, if $\rm\ a\ $ is not prime, i.e.  $\rm\ a\:|\:bc\ $ but $\rm\ a\nmid b,\ a\nmid c\ $ then $\rm\ \gcd(a,b)\ $ is a *proper* factor of $\rm\,a.\,$ Moreover this gcd can be computed  when a $\rm UFD$ has a constructive Euclidean algorithm, as does $\rm \mathbb Z[i]\:$. Therefore this yields a *constructive* proof that nonprime nonunits are reducible in Euclidean domains (i.e. the nontrivial half of the [equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/alternate-definition-of-prime-number/4399#4399) of irreducible and prime elements in $\rm UFDs$).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11309/242).

Answer (score 1):

December 2021

Page 929 in Brillhart 2009  does not use letters $n,o,p,q$  so I can display the general product thing: $$  no = pq  $$  in positive integers.

Define $r = \gcd(n,p) .$  This gives us $$  n=rs, \; \; p=rt , \; \;  \gcd(s,t) = 1  $$
Next $rso= rtq$  and $so=tq.$  Because $s,t$ are coprime, we know $t|o.$  We define $o=tu.$ Then  $so=tq$  takes us to $stu = tq$  and then $su = q.$  Again, because $s,t$ are coprime,  we see $\gcd(o,q) = \gcd(tu, su)  = u \; . \; \; $

All together, $no=pq$   tells us
$$ n=rs \; , \; \; o=tu \; , \; \; p=rt \; , \; \; q=su \; . \; \;   $$

$$   \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Alright, Brillhart writes an odd integer  $N=a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2,$   with odd $a,c$ and even $0<b<d. \; \;$

Then he writes $$   (a-c)(a+c) = (d-b) (d+b)  $$  From  our earlier  calculation $no=pq$  we are setting $n=(a-c), \; o= (a+c), \; p=  (d-b), \; q=(d+b) ,  $ all of which are even.   The outcome  was   new letters $r,s,t,u$ with $ n=rs \; , \; \; o=tu \; , \; \; p=rt \; , \; \; q=su \; . \; \;   $  Here $r = \gcd(a-c,d-b)$ is even,  while   $u = \gcd(a+c,d+b)$   is also even. Let me put these together,
$$(a-c)= rs, \;  (a+c)= tu, \;   (d-b)=rt, \; (d+b)=su   $$
From the hypothesis $N=a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2,$ we reach finally
$$  \left(   \left( \frac{r}{2}  \right)^2 +  \left( \frac{u}{2}  \right)^2    \right)  (s^2 + t^2) $$
$$  =  \frac{1}{4} \left( (rs)^2 + (rt)^2 + (su)^2 + (tu)^2  \right)   $$
$$  =  \frac{1}{4} \left( (a-c)^2 + (d-b)^2 + (d+b)^2 + (a+c)^2  \right)   $$
$$  =  \frac{1}{4} \left( 2a^2 + 2 b^2 + 2 c^2 + 2 d^2  \right)  = N $$

Comment: It would be better to include this in your prior answer.