# Some questions in proof of Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have some questions after reading this post: [Fermat's Christmas theorem on sums of two squares with Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11301/993159).

In this post, the op provides a proof of Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares. However, I'm confused about the following part:

It said that $p$ is not a Gaussian prime. Thus $$\begin{align*}
p=\alpha \beta=(a+bi)(c+di)
\end{align*}$$ I think this means that $p$ can be factored into the multiplication of two complex numbers.

My questions are

1. Are $a+bi$ and $c+di$ Gaussian primes?
2. Why are the norms of two complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ greater than one?
   Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: You do not assume they are primes, just that they are Gaussians that are not units, And because they are not units, their complex norm is not $1$. The complex norm of $a+bi$ is $1$, if and only if $(a+bi)(a-bi)=1$, if and only if $a+bi$ has multiplicative inverse $a-bi$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Then I want to ask why none of them is a unit. I know units in Gaussian integers are only $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$. If, for example, I let $c+di=1$, then $p=a+bi$, and since $p$ is real, I can get $b=0$. I'm not really able to see what makes $a+bi$ and $c+di$ not units here.

Comment: If $p$ is not a prime, then it can be factored as a product of two Gaussians that are non-units, so you take two non-units whose product is $p$. You *choose* them to be non-units, witnesses to the asserted fact that $p$ is not a prime in the Gaussians.

Comment: Thanks. About p is not a Gaussian prime, then it can be factored into the product of two non-units. Is there a proof of it?

Comment: Primes are always irreducible elements, and the **definition** of irreducible is that it is a non-unit such that if you factor it as a product of two factors, then one of the factors is a unit. (In the Gaussians, you also have Unique Factorization, so irreducibles are primes, but that does not hold in arbitrary integral domains).