# How can I solve $m^2+n^2=5077$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

$\forall (m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}$, I'm looking for an efficient way to solve this equation 
$$ m^2+n^2=5077 $$

Comment: Since $\sqrt{5077}<71$, there aren't too many combinations to try.

Comment: By inspection, if you try  $m =71$, then $n = 6$ and $n = -6$

Comment: See Bill Dubuque's reference in this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-do-you-prove-that-a-prime-is-the-sum-of-two-squares-iff-it-is-congruent-to-1#comment4726_1925

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to talk about efficient algorithm to solve an equation with just one predefined numerical parameter. The equation $m^2 + n^2 = a$ with some parameter $a$ - that's what we need to address (possibly with some conditions on $a$).

Answer (score 4):

There are algorithms for writing $rs$ as a sum of two squares if you already have $r$ and $s$ as sums of two squares.  By using the identity on complex numbers

$$(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac+bd) + (bc-ad)i$$

and taking absolute values, you get

$$(a^2+b^2) (c^2+d^2) = (ac+bd)^2 + (bc-ad)^2.$$

Unfortunately 5077 is prime, so this doesn't help.  But as Vadim has pointed out there aren't too many combinations to try.  Also useful here is [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares): an odd prime can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if it's of the form $4k+1$.  Since 5077 is of that form you're guaranteed to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since $p = 5077$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$, we know it can be factorized as

$$5077 = (m + ni)(m - ni),\quad m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

over the [Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
Furthermore, the two factors $m \pm ni$ are primes over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

To find $m + ni$, one first find an integer $x : 1 \le x < p$ such that

$$x^2 + 1 = 0 \pmod p \quad \iff x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p\tag{*1}$$

We known $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, the non-zero elements of the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, forms a cyclic group with respect to multiplication. If we randomly picking an integer $y : 2 \le y < p$ and by chance picked a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, then $y^k$ will be one possible choice of $x$.

In fact, if we pick $y = 2$, we find
$$x = \mod(2^{\frac{p-1}{4}}, p ) = \mod( 2^{1269}, 5077 ) = 4219$$
satisfies $(*1)$. Now

$$\begin{align}
& 4219^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5077} \\
\implies & 5077\;|\; 4219^2 + 1\\
\implies & \gcd{}_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(5077,4219+i) \ne 1\\
\implies & \gcd{}_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(5077,4219+i) = m + n i \text{ or } m - n i
\quad( \text{ up to units over } \mathbb{Z}[i] )
\end{align}$$

The Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is known to be an [Euclidean domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) and we can compute the GCD between
any pair of its elements using some form of Euclidean algorithm.

Let's take $5077$ and $4219 + i$ as an example.

1. Initialize 
   $$\begin{cases}
   a &\leftarrow 4219 + i\\
   b &\leftarrow 5077\end{cases}$$
2. The closest Gaussian integer to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{4219 + i}{5077}$ is $1$.
   Update the values of $(a,b)$ as
   $$\begin{cases}
   a &\leftarrow b = 5077\\
   b &\leftarrow a - 1 \times b = -858 + i\\
   \end{cases}$$
3. The closest Gaussian integer to $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{5077}{-858+i}$ is $-6$.
   Update the values of $(a,b)$ as
   $$\begin{cases}
   a & \leftarrow b = -858+i\\
   b & \leftarrow a - (-6) \times b = -71 + 6i\\
   \end{cases}
   $$
4. Since $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-858+i}{-71+6i} = 12 + i$ is an Gaussian integer,
   the algorithm terminates and the desired GCD is $-71 + 6i$.

As a consequence, $$5077 = 71^2 + 6^2$$

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution  $6^2+71^2=5077$
I have found it by trial and error

Comment: I know how to solve it by trail and error.I need how can I solve it analytically

Comment: Click `Methods` on the page I've suggested and look for *elliptical* equations. There is a more general form, than yours, but idea is the same.

Comment: @HEKTO Unfortunately the section on elliptical equations just says to use brute force to try it for all integers in the feasible interval.

Comment: @ErickWong - agreed, but the OP asked "how to solve it", not "how to solve it in a best possible way".

Comment: Also agreed.  @EEE Please revise your question to indicate that you are looking for an efficient way to solve this, and be very specific about your requirements.

Comment: Find some capital letters as well. Your sentence is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Quadratic Diophantine Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html).

There is online solver for such equations - please see [here](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM). Also, there is a lot of info about *methods* of solving this kind of equations on this page.

Comment: Hmmm, as great as Dario Alpern's solver is, it doesn't seem like it has any mention of algorithms for efficiently writing down a number as the sum of two squares.