# How can transform a product into sum of two squares

Tags: diophantine-equations, integers

How can I transform the product 365(15^2+16^2) into sum of two squares???

Comment: There are sixty-four different integer solutions to $x^2+y^2=365(15^2+16^2)$... are you looking for any particular solution or all of them?

Comment: Any of them. I need the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How do you prove that a prime is the sum of two squares iff it is congruent to 1 mod 4?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-do-you-prove-that-a-prime-is-the-sum-of-two-squares-iff-it-is-congruent-to-1)

As $365=5\cdot73$

$5=1^2+2^2$

$73=8^2+3^2$

Use [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity)  $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac\pm bd)^2+(ad\mp bc)^2$$